# Если запрошенный файл существует в нужной папке, перейти на него, иначе выдать другой (.htaccess)

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess, apache

Нужно, чтобы при любом запросе сначала происходила проверка на существование запрашиваемого файла в папке **public**. Если такой файл существует, то сделать редирект на него, а иначе делать редирект на **core.php**, который уже сам дальше решает, что делать.

Например:

- **site.com/favicon.ico** выдает соответсвующий файл, физически находящийся в **{корневая директория сайта}/public/favicon.ico** (если он там, конечно же, есть)
- **site.com/users** переходит на **core.php** (если в public нет файла users)

В .htaccess сделал такую конструкцию (часть ее нашел в интернете):

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core.php [L]
```

Как я понимаю, оно делает (или должно делать) следующее:

1. **Первый RewriteRule** выдаст запрошенный файл с приставкой public, если соотвествуюший файл существует (что проверяется через RewriteCond)
2. **Последний RewriteRule** является правилом "по-умолчанию", который срабатывает (или должен срабатывать), когда все предыдущие правила не сработали.

Честно говоря, не до конца понимаю что такое $0. Нагуглил про это такое: "Обратные связи $N на шаблоны в RewriteRule", но это совершенно ничего не объясняет, если не запутывает еще больше.

**Проблема в том**, что так почему-то **все** запросы переходят в **core.php**. Когда я убираю последний RewriteRule, оно работает как надо, но тогда есть прямой доступ ко всем остальным файлам и появляется невозможность динамической генерации виртуальных путей через скрипт. Уже перепробовал много различных вариантов, искал и в документации htaccess, но в итоге все равно получается ерунда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема решена.** Надо было, при преобразовании на `core.php` дать прямой доступ к папке `public`. То есть, сначала запрос `site.com/favicon.ico` преобразуется в `site.com/public/favicon.ico`, но указанные изначально `RewriteRule` сами же сначала ищут файл в папке `public`, потому в данном случае будет происходить поиск файла `site.com/public/public/favicon.ico`, которого, собственно и не существует. Поэтому запрос всегда и переходил на core.php.

```
#Если по заданному запросу существует файл в папке public
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
#Переходим на него
#$0 - это первое выражение в скобках, то есть (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$0 [L]

#По умолчанию всегда переходим на core.php
#При этом нужно разрешить входить в папку public напрямую,
#чтобы можно было реализовать правила выше
RewriteRule !(^public/) core.php [L]
```